# How to get first X files with node glob

Tags: node.js, glob, minimatch

Using [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob), is it possible to specify a pattern that will return only the first X matching files, rather than all matches?

For example, if I wanted all JavaScript files, my pattern would be `**/*.js`. But what if I only wanted the first 5 JavaScript files?

I realize that there are other options, such as I could take the resulting fileset array and slice it. The underlying case here makes that difficult, so I am trying to accomplish this directly from the glob pattern.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own Glob object like this:

```
var i = 0;
var Glob = require("glob").Glob;
var mg = new Glob(pattern, options, cb);
mg.on("match", function(matched) {
    console.log(matched);
    i++;
    if(i == 5) mg.abort();
});
```

It is an event emitter so you can listen for `match` event which will be fired when a file is found. With each match increase the counter and if it has reached your threshold you can call `mg.abort()` to stop the search.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, I am looking for possibilities that use only the string pattern. I'm using an application that only exposes the pattern, and no way to access the Glob directly, or to pass in a new glob.